# Creating wifi scanning as a android service

Tags: android, service, timer, wifimanager

Currently writing a wifi positioning program and i need to scan the surrounding for active APs so as to calculate the current position of the user. However, user can set the time (0-10 secs)  at which the app initiate WiFi scanning (for example, 5 sec, the program would initiate WiFi scanning every 5 secs). And from what is stated in [here] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService) and it says "application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.". So was wondering whether it is best to create a Service in my program then running a TimerTask in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, i would use Service and TimerTask like [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the the comment and also the link. So it would be like a TimerTask would call the Service at regular interval to perform the WiFi scanning.

Comment: is it possible to sent some variable to the Service?

Comment: I'm new in this area too, but I think you can do it. You can connect from your Activity to the Service and then use his methods. I worked with vogellas tutorial, and I think you should do the same too, especially the last codeblock is interesting for you. [service tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) To sent some variable to the Service, I would create some member variables in the service with getters and setters and initialize them from your Activity wich connect to the service, dont know if there is a smarter way.